# Android app lags when using hdpi resources

Tags: android

I have run into a rather strange problem. I am making a game for Android and until now I have been using sprites that are in the baseline (mdpi) density. Basically I would dump all my sprites into the `/res/drawable` folder; there are no folders for different screen densities yet. I am currently testing my app on a physical device whose screen density is hdpi, so naturally I made a `/res/drawable-hdpi` folder and I put all the scaled bitmaps in there. However, my app seems to be running really slow; when it tries to draw and animate all the game objects there is a huge lag. This does not happen when I used the contents of the `/res/drawable` folder.

I have tried to play around with the `supports-screens` tag in my AndroidManifest.xml file but they didn't really seem to do much. This is what I had:

```
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Surely there is more to using bitmaps for different densities than just simply dumping the scaled versions in their respective folders.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. If you are writing a game, and using the Android surface to do so, this is going to happen. If your game is early in development, I would suggest porting what you have to OpenGL. There is no hardware acceleration using a standard surface (at least, not yet). My only suggestion if you're going to stay in surface mode, optimize optimize optimize. Bump all your graphics down to 256 colors, only use transparency when you absolutely have to, and give users a lot of options for performance. Like turning off backgrounds, or using low-resolution resources, etc.

Comment: I am at the stage where I wouldn't want to switch over to OpenGL. Considering that this is my first app, I think I can get away with using the Canvas. Also, is OpenGL that much better when it comes to 2D graphics? I thought it was mainly known for 3D graphics. Opinions?

Comment: The issue comes down to memory, and hardware acceleration. Standard surfaces are not hardware accelerated and are housed in the VM memory heap (which by the way is extremely limited). GL surfaces are hardware accelerated and you gain access to all the memory on the device. When you use a GL texture and use the GL engine to manipulate it, you're using the hardware to speed up that process. If you use a standard surface, you're using software to blit the objects to the screen, which of course is a lot slower.